# Facebook Like Button on Dev Site

Tags: facebook-like

I'm trying to implement a Facebook Like button for a website. I'm working in a dev environment with fake content. Is there a way to "fake" the count so that I can see what the button looks like with 1, 2, 3, and even 4 digit counts? I want to make sure my design works when there is no count and when there are different counts with varying widths.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simplest (but not permanent) way is to find element containing number in developer console in browser and change its value.

Comment: Thanks mifki! That's what I've done...it's slightly different than the real thing, which is frustrating. Thanks thought...good suggestion!

Comment: You mean it looks different as if that value were actually from FB?

Comment: The iFramed HTML looks a bit different. It works fine though. I wish there was a better way, but this looks to be it.

Comment: Wait, if you use simple Like button, why can't use just specify some other known url which has as many likes as you wish?

Comment: Yeah...I tried that and it didn't work. I'm guessing Facebook prevents that type of trickery.

Comment: I just tried it again myself and you are 100% right. I'm not sure what I was doing before to make it not work. Do you want to add that as an answer? I'll mark it as the correct one in order to help future stackoverflow visitors. Thanks again.

Comment: done. and had to type some more chars to submit this comment:)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to temporary specify some other URL instead of your own that is known to have as many likes as you wish. For example `http://facebook.com/platform`